# EJB3 vs Data Access Objects

Tags: dependency-injection, ejb-3.0, dao

I am working on a project where we need to decide how we are going to expose our persistence layer.

There are currently two options on the table:

1) Use plain DAOs. These would implement an interface and be injected (probably using Weld) in the Business Components which are EJBs. Internally they would use JPA/Hibernate for persistence.

2) Rather than injecting the DAOs using Weld, they would be implemented as EJBs, and injected with @EJB in the Business Components.

Does it really make sense to use EJBs for the persistence layer when we are not using its capabilities (e.g. transaction management - business layer deals with this)?

Is there any performance penalty in using EJB over Weld (or the other way round)?

What option would you think is best?

Comment: Are you deploying 'in container' ? Which container ?  Using EJB3 *can* potentially make deployment more straightforward. With JEE6 IMHO there is little reason to avoid EJB & many cases *for* using it.  2p worth.

Comment: What about those cases where you don't need the extra EJB features at all (e.g. security, transactions...). I think in those cases CDI is a good candidate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using EJBs for a JPA based DAO is a perfectly natural fit.

If the transaction normally starts in your business layer (which are also EJBs as you mention) the transaction will naturally propagate to them. Should you ever want to use the DAO separately, then a transaction will be started for you. You may not use this feature now, but it comes totally free should you ever need it.

Also, should you ever need to a single operation in its own transaction, then this is trivial when your DAOs are EJB based.

Injecting your business EJBs with the DAO EJBs may have a potential performance advantage. As only stubs are injected that delegate to pooled instances, injection is relatively cheap. You can inject your business EJBs with many DAOs that may or may not all be necessary for every call. I'm not 100% sure CDI has this exact same capability. It of course has scoping and conversations but not really stubs to delegate to a pool.

Should you ever need JPA's `extended persistence context`, then the stateful session bean is practically made for that, otherwise the stateless session bean would be used for DAOs.

That said, CDI is the more modern component model and the current thinking seems to be that EJB will eventually be retrofitted as a set of CDI annotations. Starting to build up a CDI codebase and knowledge now may actually be a long term strategic benefit, and thus bodes for CDI.

So to answer your question more directly: yes it makes sense to use EJBs for the persistence layer, but neither EJB or CDI are absolutely a *wrong* choice here.

Comment: Very detailed reply. My main concern would be: if I have one DAO per table, then creating a pool of DAO instances can be a little bit too much - it would make sense to use then the new @Singleton beans from EJB 3.1?

Also, I am not using transactions at the DAO level and don't plan to use them, as well as any other EJB capabilities (e.g. security). From what I have read, this should be the decider between using EJBs or CDI. What do you think?

Comment: *if I have one DAO per table, then creating a pool of DAO instances can be a little bit too much* - you don't have to worry about this. Instances will be created on demand, not upfront. This means you can inject you business beans with many different DAOs, only stubs will be injected and instances will only be created when you actually access a stub. Afterwards the instance will be kept in a pool. If you are worried about the pool, you can tune it (max keep alive, max instances kept), but this is hardly ever a problem in practice.