# (Open-)JPA 1.0: OneToMany-related list is null, when fetching in lazy mode

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, null-pointer

I have a problem with JPA 1.0 (OpenJPA)

Following situation

```
@Entity
public class A{
    private Long aId;
    private List<B> bEntities;
    //myId getter and setter
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="referencedA")
    public List<B> getBEntities(){
        return bEntities;
    }
    public void setBEntities(List<B> bEntities){
        this.bEntities = bEntities;
    }
}
```

,

```
@Entitiy
public class B{
    private Long bId;
    private Long aId;
    private A referencedA;
    //aId/bId getter and setter
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID", referencedColumnName="A_ID")
    public A getReferencedA(){
        return referencedA;
    }
    public void setReferencedA(A referencedA){
        this.referencedA = referencedA;
    }
}
```

If I perform the following JPQL-Query it works as expected, meaning that each attribute is filled:

```
select object(o) from B o
```

But if I want to get all As:

```
select object(o) from A o
```

and I try to get the B-List via aReceivedAObject.getBEntities(); it returns null.

If I change or rather extend the OneToMany annotation as follows:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="referencedA", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

everything works as expected.

BUT I need lazy fetching because everything else will be much too slow.

I really hope that someone can help me solving the issue as I'm stuck to the problem for three days now :(

Notes, in case its important:
I (must) use Websphere 6.1 (with Feature-Pack for EJB 3.0), which uses OpenJPA 1.0. So it's a JavaEE project.
As far as I understood the OpenJPA-Doc I need to enable the enhancement, what I have done  as described here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0612_barcia/0612_barcia.html#sec4f
But this doesn't seem to make any difference :(

Thanks in advance!!!
Kind Regards,
asotbb

//edit: corrected typo: changed "public List getBEntities()" to "public List getBEntities()"

Comment: Couple of things to help narrow down issues:

     `public List<A> getBEntities()`

Should be:
 
`public List<B> getBEntities(){`
Secondly your JPQL seems broken why are you doing the Object(o)? Why not just o? Is the Object creation necessary? 

Lastly, where are you calling `aReceivedAObject.getBEntities()`? Can you post where that is happening? The reason I ask is if you are calling it after you have left the persistence context those Lazy loaded entities will not be found.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! 1. List<A> was a typo. 2. I tried this earlier but it didn't make any difference. 3. persistence context is a good point, as I use a session bean and inject the persistence context in there, only.
<pre><code>@Entitiy
public class ADAL{
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;
    
}  

</code></pre>

Comment: Sorry:
<pre><code>
    @Entitiy
    public class ADAL{
        @PersistenceContext
        EntityManager entityManager;
    
        public Collection<A> findAll(){
            Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuerey("findAll_A");
            return query.getResultList();
        }
    }
</code></pre>
And from another class I call ADAL's findAll method. And in this other class I then call aReceivedAObject.getBEntities(). So may it be necessary that I need to inject the persistence context in the entity classes, too? Or in all my classes?  Thx!  Kind Regards,  asotbb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And from another class I call ADAL's
>   findAll method.

Yeah that is your issue, if it is not persistence aware, you will need to make that class aware of the persistence context if you want ReceivedAObject.getBEntities() to work with lazy loading.

Having persistence conexts all over the place though can get messy as you may be forced to manually merge entities between them. Another way you could do it is have that `getBEntities()` method be wrapped in the Data Access Layer (ADAL).

Comment: Hi, okay it begins to make some sense;) Now I ask myself how to implement such a wrapper method best in ADAL:   `    public List<B> getBEntities(A detachedA){    A attachedA = entityManager.merge(detachedA);     return attachedA.getBEntities();` Is this the "recommended" way or does someon has a better solution? (Another solution I found, but I refused, was to make ADAL a stateful session bean and set persistence context type to extended: `@PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)`, but I need a stateless one...just in case somebody needs) Kind Regards, asotbb

Comment: Me again;) I'd like to rephrase my question: we are porting our application from EJB 2.1 to 3.0 (with concerns the entities most) and now wonder if our approach, using a Data Access Layer is still a good idea or common? Or do we need to establish a new approach for our concerns, using JPA now? Are there any new patterns or best practices for JPA right now?

Comment: I won't comment on that but you can check this out: [EJB VS DAO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950693/ejb3-vs-data-access-objects)

Answer (score 0):

If you use OneToMany in lazy mode, and you want to use it outside of the transaction, it will be null, or the empty list, depends on what is the initialized filed value (inside of the transaction the JPA will make another query to select, so it will be a filled list). Use `select o from A o join fetch o.as a` (if in the class B the List as field called as). Or use `left join fetch`, depends on your needs.

Comment: You should format your answer. Here comes a guide about [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)